# Making Inspector Sidebar in macOS Window

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nssplitview, nstabview

I would like to make an "inspector sidebar" in a macOS window. You know the inspector in Xcode:

[image: Xcode inspector]

The sidebar's content should be context sensitive. Depending on the user's selection in the main window there should be different dialogs.

Which technologies do I have to use to get this behavior?

My attempts were (in Storyboard):

1. Insert a Split View into the window.
2. Insert a Tab View Controller into the right Custom View of the Split View

But this didn't worked: I could easily insert the Split View into the window. And I could easily insert a Tab View Controller to the Storyboard. But I was not able to insert the Tab View Controller into the right view of the Split View.

So how do I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Insert the TabView control, not a view controller into the Split guy.

Comment: @ElTomato, when I use a TabView control, how can I setup ViewControllers for the different dialogs?

Comment: What are the things that you call 'different dialogs'?

Comment: @ElTomato, I don't know the exactly term. For example, in a Xcode storyboard: When I select a SplitView, I get a special "dialog" in the inspector where I can customise the SplitView (see the picture above). When I select another object, I get a different "dialog". The same way I would like to have different "dialogs" in the sidebar, each with different controls.

Comment: How did you insert the Split View Controller into the window?

Comment: @Willeke, in Storyboard: First I have a ViewController Scene with a ViewController. The ViewController has a View which has a SplitView. The SplitView has two CustomViews. Now I could insert a TabView into the second CustomView (but how do I get controllers for the different tabs?). Or I could insert a TabViewController into the storyboard. But how do I insert the tabs into the CustomView of the SplitView?

Comment: Use a Split View Controller?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue. I had to add a CustomView to each of the tab's CustomViews. This way, Xcode added ViewControllers automatically. Here are the individual steps:

**First,** I had to insert a SplitView into the storyboard. Nothing problematic here yet.

[image: SplitView]

**Second,** I've added a TabView (Style: tabless) into one of the CustomViews:

[image: SplitView with TabView]

**And third,** I needed to add ContainerViews to each of the tabs:

[image: SplitView with TabViews with ContainerViews]

This way Xcode added ViewControllers for each of the tab's ContainerViews:

[image]

No I can chose the different Tabs programmatically:

```
@IBAction func showInspector1(_ sender: NSButton) {
    self.tabView.selectTabViewItem(at: 0)
}
@IBAction func showInspector2(_ sender: NSButton) {
    self.tabView.selectTabViewItem(at: 1)
}
```

I would like to thank for the comments, that helped me making progress and solving this issue.